# Error in NuxtJS: Cannot Convert Undefined or Null to Object

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I am getting the following error (it won't even get to the `console.log` part of my code):

```
 ERROR  error in cloudinary module Cannot convert undefined or null to object                                                                                         09:05:40  

  at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
  at setSignature (modules\cloudinary\index.js:15:14)
```

Here is my code:

`modules/cloudinary/index.js`:

```
export default function () {

  this.nuxt.hook('render:setupMiddleware', (app) => {
    app.use('/api/cloudinary/signature', setSignature)
  })

  function setSignature(req, res) {
    try {
      const payload = []

      Object.keys(req.body).forEach((key) => {
        payload.push(`${key}=${req.body[key]}`)
      })

      console.log(payload)

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('error in cloudinary module', error)
    }
  }
}
```

Something going on with the Object here. Anyone spot anything?

**Updated:**

Doing the following console.log gives me `undefined` on the `req.body`:

```
export default function () {
  // const config = this.options.privateRuntimeConfig.cloudinary

  this.nuxt.hook('render:setupMiddleware', (app) => {
    app.use('/api/cloudinary/signature', setSignature)
  })

  function setSignature(req, res) {
    try {

      console.log(req.body)
```

Comment: which is 15. row? My guess is req.body is undefined. Console.log it

Comment: updated my question with console log

Comment: Well there is nothing in req.body, therefore you can't make Object.keys(req.body) hence the error...

Comment: Solved: I needed to import body parser:)